# How to debug what's wrong if app crashes only in release mode

Tags: flutter, debugging, build, adb

I upgraded Flutter to 2.0.0 recently and am stuck with this issue. `flutter run` and `flutter run --profile` work perfectly well, but `flutter run --release` makes app crash after startup. There is no stacktrace, there is no error or warning, there is no build issue or verbose warning, no hint really. I googled a lot, but similar questions were answered like "try to remove this line" or "try to add that line". I couldn't find any clear steps on how to *debug* what's wrong.

What steps should I take to debug this issue and find the root cause instead of trying meaningless changes on code hoping some of them will eventually fix the issue?

Comment: I face a similar problem, and it was because of a package so you need to make sure that the packages you used don't have any additional code (for example in android `build.gradle` or `AndroidManifest.xml`) or if there is you have to implement it, it's not necessary the case but it might be.

Comment: Have you tried flutter run --release -v?

Comment: Yes, but found nothing useful in the log :/

Answer (score 9):

Use `adb logcat`

OR

Enable debugging in release build, by modifying your **android/app/build.gradle**
like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When the error is code related and not in flutter itself sentry should help.

> Sentry's Flutter SDK enables automatic reporting of errors, messages,
> and exceptions.

You can import it just as any other package

```
dependencies:
  sentry_flutter: ^4.0.6
```

and configure it as early as possible in you app

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) => options.dsn = 'put_your_public_key_here',
    appRunner: () => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

To get your public key you just have to sign up on [sentry.io](http://sentry.io) and create a flutter project, no need to search for your key your it should be in the example code, it wont let you pass that point without initialiting it so you can't miss it.
The docs regarding flutter can be found [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/).

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Firebase Analytics to see error logs from your released devices from firebase. Previously it was named as Fabric.

Or you can create your own log tracker, write the logs in a file and upload the log to your server.

You can give options to user to capture log and send to server within "Advanced Settings" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

try this `flutter run --release --no-shrink`

Comment: ```Could not find an option named "no-shrink".```

Comment: try this in terminal

Comment: @AhmedRaza, is not working, I have the same error as Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have given correct permission to the app in AndroidManifest.xml, in my case I simply fixed this issue by giving camera permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

before the  tag

Answer (score -1):

In my case, after two day of confusion because app crashes only in release mode without any error on console, and errors shown in `adb logcat` not clear (unknown errors), after that I switching Flutter channel from `stable` to `master`, after run release on `master channel` errors started shown as clear messages, I solved these errors then crashes problem solved.

So my steps is:

1- Switching Flutter channel to `master` by run this command in terminal:

```
flutter channel master
```

2- Run `upgrade` command in terminal:

```
flutter upgrade
```

3- Run app as release:

```
flutter run --release
```

4- Watch console to see errors...